# list comprehension containing enumerate equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, list-comprehension, enumerate

Please what is the equivalent in javascript of this python code

```
guessed_index = [
        i for i, letter in enumerate(self.chosen_word)
        if letter == self.guess
    ]
```

Both enumerate and list comprehension are not present in the ES6 equivalent, how to I combine both ideas into one

Comment: a list comprehension is only syntactic sugar for classical loops, you can surely achieve this ;) regarding the enumerate, you can simply set up a counter that increases at each step of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focussing on the iterable/`enumerate` part of your question rather than the specific task you're performing: You can implement a JavaScript analogue of [Python's `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) using a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), and consume the resulting generator (which is a superset of an iterable) via `for-of` (or manually if you prefer):

```js
function* enumerate(it, start = 0) {
    let index = start;
    for (const value of it) {
        yield [value, index++];
    }
}

const word = "hello";
const guess = "l";
const guessed_indexes = [];
for (const [value, index] of enumerate(word)) {
    if (value === guess) {
        guessed_indexes.push(index);
    }
}
console.log(`guessed_indexes for '${guess}' in '${word}':`, guessed_indexes);
```

Or you can write a specific generator function that does the task of finding matches:

```js
function* matchingIndexes(word, guess) {
    let index = 0;
    for (const letter of word) {
        if (letter === guess) {
            yield index;
        }
        ++index;
    }
}

const word = "hello";
const guess = "l";
const guessed_indexes = [...matchingIndexes(word, guess)];

console.log(`guessed_indexes for '${guess}' in '${word}':`, guessed_indexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is useful?

```js
const word = "Hello";
const guess = "o";
const guessed_index = [...word].findIndex(letter => letter === guess);
console.log(guessed_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity for potential readers that are not proficient in python, below is the python loop equivalent of your comprehension:

```
guessed_index = []
i = 0
for letter in self.chosen_word:
    if letter == self.guess:
        guessed_index.append(i)
    i += 1
```